# If I implement Android MediaPlayer in Activity instead of Service, what'll be the problems?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I've already implemented an Android music player just in an activity instead of Service. MediaPlayer class runs in background (`onPause()`) for a long time and I noticed it doesn't stop until I destroy the app instance. So why do I need Service for media player? Is it really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You need it for when your application is running. Your activities run on the main thread (AKA the UI thread). Performing a task in the UI thread for longer than 5 seconds produces an ANR (Application is Not Responding) dialog alert. This is because you are preventing the user from interacting with your app, thus making it unresponsive.

Comment: More than 5 seconds on UI thread produces ANR?? but I didn't notice any of that kinds till now in my application.

Comment: @Md.MustafizurRahman That's because you're using your Media Player class onPause(). If your Media Player class is used when the activity is running, your application should produce ANR.

Comment: But, when a mediaplayer is playing an audio and the activity is running (not in onPause()), no ANR occurred. Isn't this your point of ANR occurred occurrence?

Comment: @Md.MustafizurRahman No, I meant ANR will occur if you implemented the code in onCreate() or onResume()

Comment: I got it... Thanks